# Rounding up in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, math, rounding

How can I round 4.39 to 5 in VB.NET?

I tried:

```
Math.Round(4.39, 0)
```

But it displays 4.

Comment: That's what 4.39 rounds to, regardless of your rounding system.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [Math.Ceiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48.aspx) in order to round a number to the closest, larger,  integer value:

```
Math.Ceiling(4.39)
```

As explained in the MSDN link:

> "Returns the smallest integral value that is greater than or equal to
>   the specified double-precision floating-point number."